# Table is not updated from another component post request angular

Tags: angular, components

I have another problem because i am not an expert in angular i have to ask what to do in order to resolve my issue.

My issue is that i have one component where i get the data from the db.json in a table but on another component i have a form that creates new entries in the db.

The point is that the table in the first component is not updated when a new entry is entered in the db.json file.

The database is updated but it is not shown. I am also using a service file.. Here is the code of the components:

serv.service.ts:

```html
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { 
    HttpClient, 
    HttpHeaders, 
    HttpParams, 
    HttpEventType 
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { map, tap, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { throwError, Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class serv{

    public usersData:any = [];

    constructor (
        private http: HttpClient
    ){}

    getData(){
        const url = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
        return this.http.get(url)
            //console.log(this.usersData)
            //console.log(this.usersData)
        
    }

    delData(id: number){
        //console.log(id)
        return this.http.delete(
            `http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`
        )
    }

    postData(postData: any){
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users', postData)
    }
}
```

list.component.ts - this is the first component where the table is shown

```html
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { serv } from '../services/serv.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  
  userdata: any = [];

  show: boolean = false;


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private serv: serv,

  ){}

  getData(){
    
    this.serv.getData().subscribe(
      data => {this.userdata = data
    })
    // .subscribe((res) => {

    // })
  }

  delData(id: number){
    //console.log(id)
    this.serv.delData(id).subscribe((res) => {
      //this.usersData = res;
      this.getData();
    })
  }

  changeData(){
    this.show = !this.show
    document.querySelector(".inputRow").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.querySelector(".showRow").classList.add("hidden")
  }

  exitData(){
    document.querySelector(".inputRow").classList.add("hidden")
    document.querySelector(".showRow").classList.remove("hidden")
  }

  saveData(){
    this.show = !this.show
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData()
  }

}
```

list.component.html:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ид</th>
                    <th>Име и презиме</th>
                    <th>Број дозвола</th>
                    <th>Вид дозвола</th>
                    <th>Дата дозвола</th>
                    <th>Дата лекарско</th>
                    <th>Опции</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let user of userdata" class="showRow">
                    
                        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.imePrezime}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.brojDozvola}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.vidDozvola}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.dataDozvola}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.dataUverenie}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="changeData()">Измени</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="delData(user.id)">Избриши</button>
                        </td>
                    
                </tr>

                <tr *ngFor="let user of userdata" class="hidden inputRow">
                    
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.imePrezime}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.brojDozvola}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.vidDozvola}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.dataDozvola}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.dataUverenie}}</td>

                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="exitData()">Излези</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveData()">Сними</button>
                    </td>
                
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

listadd.component.ts - this is the ts file which has the post method to insert a new entry into the db

listadd.component.html:

```html
<div class="novvraboten">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="hideUnhide()">Додај нов вработен</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="hide">
    <form (ngSubmit)="submitData()" #f="ngForm">
        <div>
            <h4>Додади нов вработен</h4>
            <hr/>
    
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Име и презиме</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="imePrezime"
                name="imePrezime"
                class="form-control"
                ngModel
                required
                
              >
            </div>
            <!-- <p class="error-label" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.touched">
              This input is required.
            </p> -->
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Број на дозвола</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="brojDozvola"
                  name="brojDozvola"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  required
                  #brojdozvola="ngModel"
                >
              </div>
              <!-- <p class="error-label" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.touched">
                This input is required.
              </p> -->
    
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Вид на дозвола</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="vidDozvola"
                  name="vidDozvola"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  required
                  
                >
              </div>
              <!-- <p class="error-label" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.touched">
                This input is required.
              </p> -->
    
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Дата на истекување на дозвола</label>
                <input
                  type="date"
                  id="dataDozvola"
                  name="dataDozvola"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  required
                  
                >
              </div>
              <!-- <p class="error-label" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.touched">
                This input is required.
              </p> -->
    
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Дата на истекување на лекарско</label>
                <input
                  type="date"
                  id="dataUverenie"
                  name="dataUverenie"
                  class="form-control"
                  ngModel
                  required
                  
                >
              </div>
              <!-- <p class="error-label" *ngIf="!title.valid && title.touched">
                This input is required.
              </p> -->
    
              
    
    
            
    
            <hr/>
            <button
              type="submit"
              class="btn btn-primary"
            >Додај вработен</button>
    
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

I will be very grateful if you can tell me if this is a good way of programming also in which i have the post method into another component.

I can also make the post method which makes the new entry be in the first component but i will have a big ts file which is the least i want.

Because of that i am making this way but i encountered a problem.

Thank you

Comment: So the second component add an entity and the first never update, right? Can you make a short Stackblitz example, please?

Comment: i will make it and let you know

Comment: here is a link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygca19?file=src/app/app.component.html

Just to let you know i do not know how to start the json server on this app..
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok... now I understand the problem. So you set `public usersData: any = [];` inside your user service. That's the biggest problem. In Angular we will use `Subscriptions` and `Subjects` for such things. So in your user service add the follow:

```
private userSubject: Subject<any[]> = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUserSubject() {
    return this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }

  addNewData(data: any[]) {
    this.userSubject.next(data);
  }
```

The Subject self is private; we never handle with it directly! So return its observable with `getUserSubject()`. The `addNewData` method call its next. This will push data inside the `Subject`.

In your list component add the follow:

```
  userdata: any = [];
  userSub: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSub = this.serv.getUserSubject().subscribe(data => {
      this.userdata = data;
    })
    this.getData();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.userSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

You see the userData[] array (you have already) holds your data. But we subscribe to the userSubject **and** (really important!) we unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy`. We wanna have only one subscription per time.

So last part: In your listadd component, change your onSubmit method to this:

```
submitData() {
    console.log(this.newUserForm);
    const submittedData = this.newUserForm.value;
    this.serv.postData(submittedData).subscribe((data) => {
      this.serv.usersData.push(data);
      this.serv.addNewData(this.serv.usersData);
      this.serv.getData().subscribe((data) => {
        this.userdata = data;
      });
    });
  }
```

Note: Its not the most elegant way to set `this.serv.userData` and then set it to `addNewData()`. You can subscribe to userSubject in listadd component, too.

After this all your component will refresh like magic.

Learn more about Subscriptions and so on [here](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject).

Comment: I am sorry but i have to ask.. I made all the things you told me but i does not work as it should. It shows the inserted column but it deletes the previous columns.

Also i would like to ask about the Subscription.. Why we make a new private userSubject variable as Subject? Will we use this part to update the usersData value in the service file? Because if we want it to be private we have to use method to update the private variable? Also the addNewData method how does it get the data? From where? As far as i understand the next has to take data from somewh? I don't quite understand this..

Comment: I think i understood it.. We use subscription so we can subscribe to the Subject variable from anywhere with the method getUserSubject(). With the method addNewData() we use it to push data into the Subject variable. So i do not use the public variable in the serv file but i use the Subject to store the data from the DB.json file. I use the get method from the serv file to get the current data in the db.json.

Comment: Than with the getUserSubject() in the list component file i update the current userdata variable that is subscribed to the Subject. And the data from the form is pushed into the Subject in the listadd component with the addNewData(). Hmm very much thank you i understood the Subject now! Thank you again!